# Oracle 12c Release 2 Database Installation Error

Tags: oracle, path, installation, windows-8.1, oracle12c

I have problems  with creating a new database in Oracle 12c Release 2. Immediately after I configured the Installation and the process begins, the error message:

> `Cannot run program "C:\app\Admin\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\netca.bat": Create Process error=2, System could not find the file.`

`netca.bat` is in `..\dbhome_1\bin` located and i have also set the path in the `%PATH%` variable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By PATH you mean ORACLE_HOME?

Comment: i set the path to dbhome_1 in the ORACLE_HOME variable and the ORACLE_HOME variable into PATH

Comment: netca.bat is Net Configuration Asistant - you can ignore it and continue instalation (you can start it manually after instalation)

Comment: After click 'OK' on the error message the Database Configuration Assistant shuts down.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Oracle Database 12c on a fresh Windows 8.1. For me the solutions was deactivating a preinstalled McAfee. I used the Windows-builtin-User during the Oracle-Database Installation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is caused by enviroment settings/PATH/ORACLE_HOME

Your path should not contain `'/'`, `','` , `';'`.

Maybe you can add anenviroment variable named LANG and value `American_America.we8iso8859p15`

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't understand what you mean with "Your path should not contain `'/'`,`','`,`';'`. I think you meant `':'`. However adding the LANG variable did not help.